Network and shared storage issues when setting up a PolarDB cluster
I am encountering some issues while setting up a PolarDB cluster using the polardb_pg_devel:ubuntu22.04 image. After configuring shared storage and network, I am seeing persistent warning messages when starting the nodes, making it unclear whether the system is running correctly. Although there were errors during the shared storage formatting, it was mentioned that these could be ignored and subsequent operations proceeded normally. I am unsure of the cause of these warning messages and need assistance to resolve them.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a 20GB file on the macOS host to be used as a loop block device in containers.

mkdir ~/data_volumn  
cd ~/data_volumn  
dd if=/dev/zero of=./VirtualDisk.img bs=1m count=20480 oflag=direct  


Start containers pb1 and pb2, ensuring network connectivity between them.
In pb1, create a loop device and symlink it to nvme1n1. pb2 uses the loop device created by pb1.
Format the shared disk using sudo pfs -C disk mkfs -f nvme1n1.
Start the pfsd service in both pb1 and pb2.
Compile and deploy PolarDB 15, create a primary instance in pb1, and set up a Replica node in pb2.
Check the replication status of the shared storage to ensure data integrity.

After the node is started, the following warnings always exist:
告警来自实例本地数据目录日志文件中 $PGDATA/pg_log/xxx_error.log
... 
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:13.410 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:13.910 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:14.410 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:14.910 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:15.410 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:15.911 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:16.411 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:16.912 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:17.413 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:17.913 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:18.413 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:18.914 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:19.414 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:19.914 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:20.415 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage
207                     2024-12-24 14:48:20.915 CST     WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage

The error code comes from PolarDB external/polar_resource_manager/polar_resource_manager.c
/*
 * check ins memory
 */
void
polar_check_mem_exceed(void)
{
        Size            pfsd_rss = 0;
        Size            ins_rss_limit = 0;
        Size            ins_mem_limit = 0;
        Size            ins_mem_usage = 0;
        Size            ins_rss = 0;
        Size            ins_mapped_file = 0;

        /* Get instance memory limit and memory usage */
        if (polar_get_ins_memorystat(&ins_rss, &ins_mapped_file, &ins_rss_limit) != 0)
        {
                elog(WARNING, "Failed to get the instance memory usage");
                return;
        }

        /* Get the pfsdaemon process rss */
        if (enable_account_otherproc && polar_get_procrss_by_name("(pfsdaemon)", &pfsd_pid, &pfsd_rss) != 0)
        {
                pfsd_pid = InvalidPid;
                elog(DEBUG1, "Failed to get the pfsdaemon rss");
        }

        /* Calculate memory limit, memory request and memory usage */
        ins_mem_limit = Min(ins_rss_limit / 100 * total_mem_limit_rate, ins_rss_limit - total_mem_limit_remain_size * 1024);
        /* mapped_file is generated by DSM */
        ins_mem_usage = ins_rss + ins_mapped_file + pfsd_rss;

        /*
         * total mem usage reach mem limit evict resource manager to release
         * exceed_rss memory
         */
        /* priority to release resource manager which exceed limit */
        /* After setting the random policy, other release methods will be shielded */
        if (mem_release_policy == TERMINATE_ANY_RANDOM && ins_mem_usage > ins_mem_limit)
        {
                if (enable_log)
                        ereport(LOG, (errmsg("[polar_resource_manager] For Random Policy: Instance memory usage database memory %lu bytes, "
                                                                 "database dynamic shared memory %lu bytes, pfsd memory %lu bytes",
                                                                 ins_rss, ins_mapped_file, pfsd_rss)));

                /* The idle process will be released first */
                polar_throttle_mem_random(ins_mem_usage, ins_mem_limit, RM_TBLOCK_DEFAULT, idle_terminate_num);

                /*
                 * Since the memory size of the process is not obtained under the
                 * random policy, it is necessary to obtain the instance memory usage
                 * again to determine whether to release the active sessions.
                 */
                if (polar_get_ins_memorystat(&ins_rss, &ins_mapped_file, &ins_rss_limit) != 0)
                {
                        elog(WARNING, "Failed to get the instance memory usage");
                        return;
                }

                if (enable_account_otherproc && polar_get_procrss_by_name("(pfsdaemon)", &pfsd_pid, &pfsd_rss) != 0)
                {
                        pfsd_pid = InvalidPid;
                        elog(DEBUG1, "Failed to get the pfsdaemon rss");
                }

                ins_mem_usage = ins_rss + ins_mapped_file + pfsd_rss;

                /* If the memory still exceeds the limit, release the active session */
                if (ins_mem_usage > ins_mem_limit)
                        polar_throttle_mem_random(ins_mem_usage, ins_mem_limit, RM_TBLOCK_INPROGRESS, active_terminate_num);
        }
        else if (ins_mem_usage > ins_mem_limit)
        {
                /*
                 * When the memory is larger than the memory limit, it will perform
                 * the forced release memory mode.
                 */
                if (enable_log)
                        ereport(LOG, (errmsg("[polar_resource_manager] For Limit: Instance memory usage database memory %lu bytes, "
                                                                 "database dynamic shared memory %lu bytes, pfsd memory %lu bytes",
                                                                 ins_rss, ins_mapped_file, pfsd_rss)));

                polar_throttle_mem(ins_mem_usage, ins_mem_limit, true);
        }
}


(Several things seem odd in the setup as you describe it: you can't usually mount anything, even a loopback device, in a container; you can't usually mount the same storage multiple times; you don't normally start a container and then separately start a program inside it.  This seems like it's a question more about configuring database storage than about writing code, though.)

This is a code-related issue. There may be a problem with the code for obtaining memory status.
